# AF Binding to CosmosDb

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to output data from an Azure function to CosmosDb (MongoDb), I have the following binding setup:

```
[DocumentDB("mydatabase", "mycollection",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection", 
    CreateIfNotExists= true, 
    PartitionKey = "SomeKey")]
IAsyncCollector<MyEntity> mongoBinding,
```

In my code I do the following:

```
var entity = new MyEntity() {SomeKey="X1CLX1010000002", Data = "somedata"};
await mongoBinding.AddAsync(entity);

public class MyEntity {
    public string SomeKey {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
}
```

Results in error:

> {"Errors":["The partition key component definition path 'SomeKey'
>   could not be accepted, failed near position '0'. Partition key paths
>   must contain only valid characters and not contain a trailing slash or
>   wildcard character."]}

Any idea to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using the curly brackets around your property name? Try `PartitionKey = "{SomeKey}"`

Comment: If I change it to use curly brackets, the I get: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'BlobStorageEventHandler.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No binding parameter exists for 'SomeKey'.

Comment: `{MyEntity.SomeKey}` ?

Comment: Turns out, that the binding in Azure Functuons doesn't support MongoDb, so I had to switch to the MongoDb driver for .Net (Though using "/SomeKey" did create the collection, but I was unable to get data in there(

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add a slash at the start of your key, like `PartitionKey = "/SomeKey"`. Then partition key acts like a path, thus it needs the "/" at the start. You did not use the slash, so the above error.